# Thinkpad W520 fails to suspend

Tags: nvidia, thinkpad

Since updating to Ubuntu 12.10, my Thinkpad W520 fails to suspend properly (when closing the lid). It will stay on and not turn off. 
The little error report windows say it might be related to the proprietary nvidia driver.

Any way to debug this is appreciated, so I can file the appropriate bug reports.